# De-serialising a json that are using polymorphism (base class), in ASP.NET Core Web API (POST request) in C#

Tags: asp.net-core, polymorphism

I create a model class have polymorphism in base class, then create a post type request web api and call api using json have both property base and child class but at controller I only get base class property value not child class property value. My project is in ASP.NET Core and create a post type request web api. Language use is C#.

My model class

```
public class MyAnimals
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
}

public class Animal
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public string Says { get; set; }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public string Likes { get; set; }
}
```

My Web API `POST` handling method:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult PostAnimal([FromBody] MyAnimals myAnimals)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

My desired object want to get in myAnimals is like this:

```
{
    "description": "My favorite animals",
    "animals": 
        [
            {
                "likes": "Cheese",
                "name": "Tom"
            },
            {
                "says": "Bark",
                "name": "Pluto"
            }
        ]
}
```

But I didn't get the same - I only get:

```
{
    "description": "My favorite animals",
    "animals": [
        {
            "name": "Tom"
        },
        {
            "name": "Pluto"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please help me with this. Thanks to you - help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because you only have the `Name` attribute in your parent class, if you want the returned result to have child class fields, you should return the child class.

You can customize a `JsonCreationConverter<T>`:

```
public abstract class JsonCreationConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// this is very important, otherwise serialization breaks!
    /// </summary>
    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    /// <summary> 
    /// Create an instance of objectType, based properties in the JSON object 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="objectType">type of object expected</param> 
    /// <param name="jObject">contents of JSON object that will be 
    /// deserialized</param> 
    /// <returns></returns> 
    protected abstract T Create(Type objectType, JObject jObject);

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType,
          object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        // Load JObject from stream 
        JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        // Create target object based on JObject 
        T target = Create(objectType, jObject);

        // Populate the object properties 
        serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), target);

        return target;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value,
          JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then you can use `JsonConverterAttribute` now:

```
public class MyAnimals
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
}
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyCustomConverter))]
public class Animal
{
    public string Name { set; get; }

    private class MyCustomConverter : JsonCreationConverter<Animal>
    {
        protected override Animal Create(Type objectType,
          Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject jObject)
        {
            //TODO: read the raw JSON object through jObject to identify the type
            if (jObject.Value<string>("says")!=null)
            {
                return new Dog();
            }
            return new Cat();

            //now the base class' code will populate the returned object.
        }
    }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public string Says { get; set; }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public string Likes { get; set; }
}
```

Don't forget to install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` and register it:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Controller:

```
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult PostAnimal([FromBody] MyAnimals myAnimals)
    {
        return Ok(myAnimals);
    }
}
```

Test Result:
[image]

Comment: Hi @Pratyush Singh, did my answer help you?